# One member of font family fails to import into iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uitextview, uifont

I am having trouble importing one of my fonts: "Gotham-Bold"
(All the other fonts in the Gotham Family work.

I followed the steps listed here: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/#includefonts

When I,

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

I get a list of all my available fonts:

```
2014-05-27 11:33:08.505 Gotham
2014-05-27 11:33:08.506   Gotham-Black
2014-05-27 11:33:08.507    Gotham-BoldItalic
2014-05-27 11:33:08.508    Gotham-Bold
2014-05-27 11:33:08.509    Gotham-UltraItalic
2014-05-27 11:33:08.510    Gotham-Medium
```

Gotham is clearly there.

It's also in my plist and build settings.

When I,

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Bold" size:22.0];


NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                            forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:scrollViewHeader.attributedText.string attributes:attrsDictionary];
[attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromArray:@[@140, @200, @70]] range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length)];

scrollViewHeader.attributedText = attrString;
```

My font just registers "Gotham," on inspection.

```
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.54902 0.784314 0.27451 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x14d4c5c0> font-family: \"Gotham\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 22.00pt";
}
```

**Question:** Any idea why one font in the might not be imported? Ways to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: If all of the other fonts in the family work, I suspect something might be wrong with the actual font file. Where did you get the files? Are you using a licensed copy of this font?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It is licensed and legitimately obtained through the clients company. Everything displays fine in word/system/chrome when I open the otf/ttf file.

Comment: I would guess that `Gotham` (Regular), `Gotham-Black`, `Gotham-BoldItalic`, `Gotham-Bold`, `Gotham-UltraItalic`, and `Gotham-Medium` are all be part of the `Gotham` font **family**. It looks like the `NSLog()` may only be showing you that the font **family** is `Gotham`, and not printing the actual `fontName`. Have you tried logging the `fontName` to see what that is?